# Contract accept USDT transfer

Tags: usdt

EDIT: Test done on BNB blockchain

I am trying to have a function called from customer to send USDT to the contract address.

Contract creator address is 0x0ca34ACE2457AD514891DE45ADD48243aeAFd0Be
Contract is 0x5b8b6FDcd5c6c718A364CBB54b4bb084F1Eab866

When I call the function, I am calling if from sender 0x3e8FA613AB7dBc78900a36Ce6A9fa2A7CFe5EE61 to 0x0ca34ACE2457AD514891DE45ADD48243aeAFd0Be with amount 5$ I get "We were not able to estimate gas. There might be an error in the contract and this transaction may fail." and the fee is huge.

I even go to 0x3e8FA613AB7dBc78900a36Ce6A9fa2A7CFe5EE61 address and approve 5$ for 0x0ca34ACE2457AD514891DE45ADD48243aeAFd0Be and for 0x5b8b6FDcd5c6c718A364CBB54b4bb084F1Eab866.
I am a little confused here, can someone explain me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

function buyCoin(address _to, uint256 _amount) external {
ERC20 usdt = ERC20(0x337610d27c682E347C9cD60BD4b3b107C9d34dDd);
require(usdt.transfer(_to, _amount), "Failed to send USDT");
}

Comment: Can you please mention the chain/network name ?

Comment: Hello, yes, sorry. BNB

Answer (score 1):

You need to call [approve function of the USDT token contract](https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0x337610d27c682E347C9cD60BD4b3b107C9d34dDd#writeContract#F1) that you’re using in the `buyCoin()` function for creating an instance of ERC20, with these arguments:

**spender:** `0x5b8b6FDcd5c6c718A364CBB54b4bb084F1Eab866` (i.e., your contract address containing the `buyCoin()` function, as it’s the one transferring the USDT tokens on your behalf)

**amount:** `5000000000000000000` (i.e., 18-decimal representation of 5 USDT)